# How to apply a function to a dask dataframe and return multiple values?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

In pandas, I use the typical pattern below to apply a vectorized function to a df and return multiple values. This is really only necessary when the said function produces multiple independent outputs from a single task. See my overly trivial example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'val1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'val2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

def myfunc(in1, in2):
    out1 = in1 + in2
    out2 = in1 * in2
    return (out1, out2)

df['out1'], df['out2'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x['val1'], x['val2']), axis=1))
```

Currently I write a separate function to chunk the pandas df and using multiprocessing for efficiency gains, but I would like to use dask to accomplish this task instead. Continuing the example, here is how I would run a vectorized function to return a single value when using dask:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

def simple_func(in1, in2):
    out1 = in1 + in2
    return out1

df['out3'] = ddf.map_partitions(lambda x: simple_func(x['val1'], x['val2']), meta=(None, 'i8')).compute()
```

Now I would like to use dask and return two values as in the pandas example. I have tried to add a list to meta and return a tuple but just get errors. Is this possible in dask and how?

Comment: At the moment there is no easy way (that I know of) to map a multi-output function across a dataframe.  You might try using [dask.delayed in combination with dask.dataframe](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed-collections.html)

Answer (score 7):

I think the problem here stems from the way you are combining your results is not great. Ideally you would use `df.apply` with the `result_expand` argument and then use `df.merge`. Porting this code from Pandas to Dask is trivial. For pandas this would be:

### Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

def return_two_things(x, y):
    return (
        x + y,
        x * y,
    )

def pandas_wrapper(row):
    return return_two_things(row['val1'], row['val2'])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'val1': range(1, 6),
    'val2': range(1, 6),
})

res = df.apply(pandas_wrapper, axis=1, result_type='expand')
res.columns = ['out1', 'out2']
full = df.merge(res, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(full)
```

Which outputs:

```
   val1  val2  out1  out2
0     1     1     2     1
1     2     2     4     4
2     3     3     6     9
3     4     4     8    16
4     5     5    10    25
```

### Dask

For Dask, applying the function to the data and collating the results is virtually identical:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
# here 0 and 1 refer to the default column names of the resulting dataframe
res = ddf.apply(pandas_wrapper, axis=1, result_type='expand', meta={0: int, 1: int})
# which are renamed out1, and out2 here
res.columns = ['out1', 'out2']
# this merge is considered "embarrassingly parallel", as a worker does not need to contact 
# any other workers when it is merging the results (that it created) with the input data it used.
full = ddf.merge(res, left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(full.compute())
```

Outputing:

```
   val1  val2  out1  out2
0     1     1     2     1
1     2     2     4     4
2     3     3     6     9
3     4     4     8    16
4     5     5    10    25
```

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party. Perhaps this was not possible back when the question was asked.

I don't like the ending assignment pattern. As far as I am able to find dask does not allow new column assignment like pandas does.

You need to set the meta value to the basic type you are returning. You can return a dict, tuple, set, or list quite simply from my testing. The meta doesn't actually seem to care if the type matches the type of the return object anyway.

```
import pandas
import dask.dataframe

def myfunc(in1, in2):
    out1 = in1 + in2
    out2 = in1 * in2
    return (out1, out2)

df = pandas.DataFrame({'val1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'val2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
ddf = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

df['out1'], df['out2'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x['val1'], x['val2']), axis=1))


output = ddf.map_partitions(lambda part: part.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x['val1'], x['val2']), axis=1), meta=tuple).compute()

out1, out2 = zip(*output)

ddf = ddf.assign(out1 = pandas.Series(out1))
ddf = ddf.assign(out2 = pandas.Series(out2))

print('\nPandas\n',df)
print('\nDask\n',ddf.compute())
print('\nEqual\n',ddf.eq(df).compute().all())
```

outputs:

```
Pandas
    val1  val2  out1  out2
0     1     1     2     1
1     2     2     4     4
2     3     3     6     9
3     4     4     8    16
4     5     5    10    25

Dask
    val1  val2  out1  out2
0     1     1     2     1
1     2     2     4     4
2     3     3     6     9
3     4     4     8    16
4     5     5    10    25

Equal
val1    True
val2    True
out1    True
out2    True
dtype: bool
```

It helps to note that map_partition's lambda return is a partition of the larger dataframe (based, in this case, on your npartitions value). Which you would then treat like any other dataframe with your .apply().